# PyCharm 2017.1 produces the warning ``Expected type 'int', got 'float' instead`` on a chained comparison using three float values

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm 2017.1 the following code produces the warning `Expected type 'int', got 'float' instead` on `maximum`; what am I doing wrong?

```
        minimum = 1.0
        value = 2.0
        maximum = 3.0
        if minimum <= value <= maximum:
            pass
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: It's a known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23766

Comment: OK, Thanks!  I did look around for a pre-existing ticket but I didn't run across this.  I was using Python 3.5.