# Is PyCharm complaining about this date comparison justifiably?

Tags: python, pycharm

So I'm comparing three date objects like this:

```
if (subscription_date < event_date <= present):
```

Pycharm is highlighting `subscription_date < event_date` with "Expected type 'date' got 'bool' instead". I can understand where this warning is coming from, but the code works fine as it should, AFAIK.

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: It's possible PyCharm is not correctly detecting that this will be expanded to `(subscription_date < event_date) and (event_date <= present)`, which might be a bug. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554623/3001761. Tracker issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22763. Which version are you running? It was supposedly fixed in 2017.1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PyCharm is not complaining justifiably; that will be expanded via [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) to

```
if (subscription_date < event_date) and (event_date <= present):
```

and no comparison between `bool` and `date` will take place.

It looks like there was a [reported bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22763) for this in version 2017.1, but that should have been fixed by 2017.1.4.  Depending on the version you're using, if you're still seeing this behaviour you may want to look and see if there's another open bug for your version (and report it if not).

Comment: Thanks. I’m running 2017.2.4. Too bad Jetbrains’ issue reporting is so convoluted.